# Perguntas com recompensa como excluir

Tags: suporte, recompensa

Fiz uma pergunta, ninguém respondeu, dei +50 de recompensa...ninguém respondeu..pesquisei, pesquise, descobri a resposta, publiquei, como faço para excluir?
OBS: na pergunta uma pessoa respondeu algo, que não era a solução.
Como faço?

Link da pergunta:
[Windows Phone não carrega .font em CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16539/windows-phone-nao-carrega-font-em-css/17399#17399)

Comment: Link da pergunta sff.

Comment: Você não consegue dar a recompensa a si mesmo?

Comment: Se você publicou uma resposta para um problema que teve, isso poderia ser útil para outras pessoas. Por que excluir?

Comment: Outra coisa: tudo que você publica em qualquer site do SE, passa a ser propriedade do SE. Você pode votar pela deleção de perguntas em certos casos, mas essa deleção encorre em penalidades. A filosofia é que é melhor ajeitar algo que não está bom do que perder conteúdo que potencialmente pode ajudar outras pessoas. Em geral no SE apenas coisas muito erradas como spam são deletadas sem um processo mais cuidadoso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não pode dar a recompensa a você mesmo nem excluir ela. Se, até 24 horas após o fim da recompensa você não escolher uma resposta *não-sua* manualmente, o sistema entra em ação e escolhe a resposta mais bem votada com essas características para dar *metade* do valor da recompensa:

- A resposta foi criada depois da colocação da recompensa.
- Ela tem pontuação de ao menos +2.
- A resposta não pode ter sido escrita por quem ofereceu a recompensa.

Se nenhuma resposta com esses critérios for encontrada (parece que vai ser o caso), ninguém ganha a recompensa, mas você não tem a reputação de volta.

Fonte: [**How does the bounty system work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Eu realmente estou em dúvida quanto à documentação. Eu entendo que a pessoa não pode atribuir os pontos a si mesmo. Mas na parte que fala da escolha automática sistema, não diz que ele não dá metade dos pontos se a resposta for do próprio autor. O que você acha?

Comment: @utluiz Lá fala isso também, acrescentei. De qualquer forma temos um conflito. Na postagem que citei fala que uma resposta do autor não será premiada. Mas na central de ajuda isso não é dito. Acredito que seja apenas uma omissão para não entrar em muitos detalhes, eu iria mais pelo meta. Mas não sei como isso funciona por experiencia própria.

Comment: Removi minha resposta, pedi ajuda de cima sobre isso e quando tiver uma confirmação eu aviso.

Comment: Sacanagem... pelo menos na recompensa atribuida pelo sistema o oferecedor da recompensa poderia estar elegível, já que ele criou uma boa resposta eleita pelos outros usuários.

Comment: @Math, a possibilidade de abuso disso seria *muito* grande.

Comment: @brasofilo pq abusos se a comunidade votou na resposta? Poderiam ser regras mais rígidas para conseguir os pontos de volta, tipo, ser a mais votada, ter sido postada depois de oferecer a recompensa e ter uma pontuação mínima de X, seila, 5 e não possuir nenhuma outra com mais de 1 ponto. Seria algo que não ocorreria com muita frequencia.

Comment: @Math, bom, isso é um argumento extra, o principal é o que exponho no [comentário abaixo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1468/perguntas-com-recompensa-como-excluir/1471?noredirect=1#comment4037_1475): o preço é pela publicidade, não pela resposta.

Comment: @brasofilo concordo com o preço pela publicidade, até mesmo por que se ninguém respondeu pode ser por que a pergunta não foi bem escrita ou não estava clara, etc, não estou dizendo que se aplica ao caso atual, que eu não li nem pergunta nem resposta, apenas vi os números. Mas ainda acho que existe a possibilidade de ser feita a auto-recompensa automática pelo sistema sem que houvessem abusos :) mas talvez falte interesse em desenvolver tal automatismo, já que não deve ser comum essa situação.

Answer (score -1):

estranho, não concordo se eu dou um prêmio para o melhor caçador, melhor programador, a melhor resposta, só recebe o prêmio quem for o melhor, se ninguém aparecer o prêmio fica comigo encalhado. Fiz o prêmio, ninguém pode ajudar, a premiação deveria ser devolvida.

OK; entendido que o correto seria então uma tradução como:
"Pagar destaque extra"

Comment: É que apesar do nome a lógica das recompensas é outra: é como se você estivesse pagando (em pontos) para ter sua pergunta destacada durante uma semana (na home do site e na aba "em destaque"). Por isso os pontos são descontados assim que você inicia o processo de recompensa. Inclusive tem uma mensagem bem clara nesse processo dizendo que os pontos não são reembolsáveis (embora em casos excepcionais você pode sinalizar a pergunta e um moderador *pode* decidir te reembolsar, durante a vigência da recompensa).

Comment: Em outras palavras, a pessoa paga pela publicidade, por ter a pergunta em lugar privilegiado durante 7 dias (+1). Não interessa se houve ou não respostas; ainda que normalmente há. Creio que é óbvio que a auto-recompensa daria lugar a muitos abusos.

Comment: `não concordo` Manda um email pro [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) explicando que você não gosta da metodologia de sucesso que eles desenvolveram ao longo de vários anos ;) ou então posta isso no [Meta do SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Renan, não precisa ser sarcastico, não estou falando que o SO tem uma política errada, etc, afinal se eu não gostasse dele como um geral, não estaria aqui :) apenas acho que o nome (como dito pelo vfavaretto) não reporta realmente o que é, não estou dando uma recompensa pela resposta e sim pagando pelo destaque. Creio que a palavra seria: "Pagar pontos para destaque extra" algo assim...